# IBM Worklight - What is the use of Worklight in native app development?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Why do we use Worklight in native application development. Does it have any specific advantages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating native apps, you can import to your project the Worklight Native SDK. This SDK provides API methods allowing you to access Worklight features, such as:

- Unified SMS/Push Notifications
- Remote Disable
- Remote Notify
- Adapters
- Authentication framework

You can read more about native development in Worklight, here:

- [IBM Worklight Getting Started: native development](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#native)
- [Developing native mobile apps with IBM Worklight](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1310_amrhein/1310_amrhein.html)
- [Development guidelines for using native API](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/r_development_guidelines_for_using_native_api.html)

Native development in Worklight is currently supported in: Android, iOS and JavaME.
For Hybrid apps you can add native functionality [using Native Pages and Cordova plug-ins](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova).

Comment: Using Worklight in native SDKs will give you some cool benefits like App statistics/metrics which otherwise you have to setup a separate  machine for it. And even WL Console can be utilized for advanced features like reports, user contorle ...but it all depends on how you best utilize the Worklight SDK

Comment: Worklight is useless for native app development. There are much better individual products for Analytics, Crash Reporting, Push Notification. Worklight simply introduces unnecessary bugs in native apps.